# Upgrading Application to Rails 4 issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

I've recently upgraded my rails 3.2 project to 4.0. I've been successful in upgrading my app for the most part by following the [guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0). I have a few issues that I'm not sure what direction I should go and I'm looking for some help.

I was using quite a few attr_accessible on my models that I've now removed based in the advice in the guides. The guides say :

> Rails 4.0 has removed attr_accessible and attr_protected feature in
>   favor of Strong Parameters. You can use the Protected Attributes gem
>   for a smooth upgrade path.

This gem got my application running but anytime I try to create a new object such as a user, message, etc. I get an error. From some research this seems common when using the new gem. It was suggested to remove the gem which would solve the new object issues. I did that but now I'm getting multiple errors from some of the other gems in my applications (And yes I've upgraded all gems to the most recent versions). Here is the error I'm getting:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/deprecated_mass_assignment_security.rb:14:in `attr_accessible': `attr_accessible` is extracted out of Rails into a gem. Please use new recommended protection model for params(strong_parameters) or add `protected_attributes` to your Gemfile to use old one. (RuntimeError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/acts-as-messageable-0.4.8/lib/acts-as-messageable/message.rb:8:in `<class:Message>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/acts-as-messageable-0.4.8/lib/acts-as-messageable/message.rb:4:in `<module:ActsAsMessageable>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/acts-as-messageable-0.4.8/lib/acts-as-messageable/message.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `const_get'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `block in constantize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `inject'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/acts-as-messageable-0.4.8/lib/acts-as-messageable/model.rb:34:in `acts_as_messageable'
    from /Users/dave/rails_projects/EquiptMe/app/models/user.rb:14:in `<class:User>'
    from /Users/dave/rails_projects/EquiptMe/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:423:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:423:in `block in load_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:615:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:422:in `load_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:323:in `require_or_load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:462:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `const_get'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `block in constantize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `inject'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:534:in `get'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:565:in `constantize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise.rb:278:in `get'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_used_route'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise.rb:312:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise.rb:312:in `add_mapping'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:208:in `block in devise_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `devise_for'
    from /Users/dave/rails_projects/EquiptMe/config/routes.rb:7:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:316:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:316:in `eval_block'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:294:in `draw'
    from /Users/dave/rails_projects/EquiptMe/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/dave/rails_projects/EquiptMe/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/dave/rails_projects/EquiptMe/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/dave/rails_projects/EquiptMe/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/dave/rails_projects/EquiptMe/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the master branch of the "acts-as-messageable" gem in your Gemfile? It looks like there have been some updates related to Rails 4 since it was last released. If that fixes it, I'd ping the author to see if they'd release a new version.

Comment: That worked...Thank You! I didn't even consider that. If you want to put that as the answer I'll select it. Thanks again.

Comment: Copied and pasted to answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using the master branch of the "acts-as-messageable" gem in your Gemfile. It looks like there have been some updates related to Rails 4 since it was last released. If that fixes it, I'd ping the author to see if they'd release a new version.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new gem created recently to help with upgrading from Rails 3 to Rails 4. I've used it recently and it made the upgrading process so much easier.

The gem is called [wize_upgrader](https://github.com/w1zeman1p/wize_upgrader).

One thing that this gem does with attr_accessible in rails 3 models is that is converts it into strong params for you in your controller.

i.e: (in posts_controller)

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :tag)
end
```